# How to check if user has permission to access this function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a function that check if the user has permission or not and it return **Boolean**.

**Question is**

How I check in each function user has permission or not.
For example in **users controller** I have 2 functions:

1. index(): show all users
2. delete($id): delete a single user

**index():**

```
public function index () {
    if(Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo('show all users')) {
        // continue for API
    } else {
        // response with error for API
    }
}
```

I know that there is a better way to do that because I don't want to repeat this if statement in all my functions.

**What I have tried to do:**

I have tried to create a helper function that check if user has permission and return the response error if the user doesn't have permission.
And call it in every function but it didn't work.

**Helper function code:**

```
if(!function_exists('userHasPermission')) {
    function userHasPermission ($permission) {
        $main_permission = 'do everything';
        if (!Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo($main_permission) || !Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo($permission)) {
            $res = trans('api_responses.authorization_failed');
            return Response::json([
                'message'   =>  $res['message'],
                'code'      =>  $res['code']
            ], $res['code']);
        }
    }
}
```

**index function call**

```
public function index()
    {
        // PERMISSIONS CHECK
        userHasPermission('users show active');
        $getUsers = $this -> users -> getAllActive();
        return Response::json($getUsers);
    }
```

**But it never returns the error response even if the user doesn't have permission and even it entered the if statement in my helper!**

Comment: You should read https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yea I have read it but my problem is that I don't want to check `if else` in every function in my controllers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Laravel you can use a gate for this.

In you `App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` file do something like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('do-everything', function ($user) {
        return $user->hasPermission('do-everything');
    });

    Gate::define('do-one-thing', function ($user) {
        return $user->hasPermission('do-one-thing');
    });
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
if (Auth::user()->can('do-everything')) {
    // the user can do everything
}

if (Auth::user()->can('do-one-thing')) {
    // the user can just do one thing
}
```

or

```
if (!Auth::user()->can('do-everything')) {
    abort(403);
}
// user has permission to the everything from here on
```

or in your `routes/web.php` you could do this:

```
Route::get('/things', 'ThingController@action')->middleware(['can:do-one-thing']);
```

or you can group the routes like this:

```
Route::middleware(['can:do-everything'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/things', 'ThingController@index');
    Route::get('/other-things', 'OtherThingController@index');
    ...
}
```

You can also look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization for more ideas.

Comment: My problem is that I don't want to make this `if else` statement in every controller that's why I am searching for a better method.

Comment: I already made that and I can use `can('do-everything')` but I will do the same if statement every controller function

Comment: @Ahmedessam You can also put this in your routes to keep it out of your controllers. See update in my answer.

Comment: Yea Middleware is the best solution for me.. thanks a lot.. please upvote my question it may help others.

Comment: Yea Middleware is the best solution for me.. thanks a lot.. please upvote my question it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

Your helper function returns a new response but it returns it to the controller not as HTTP response, so You can get the returned value like this:

```
public function index()
    {
        // PERMISSIONS CHECK
        $response = userHasPermission('users show active');


        $getUsers = $this -> users -> getAllActive();
        return Response::json($getUsers);
    }
```

So what you need is to check the response if it has a value
but with this approach you are going to have the same problem as your first one.

To solve it: throw exception from the helper function instead of returning some response.

**A better solution** is to use FormRequest, check this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation) to do it, be sure to check "Authorizing Form Requests" section which states the authorize function.

**EDIT:**

what you have to do is the following:

create new class let's call it "IndexRequest" that inherits from "FormRequest" class, then implement authorize method.

so something like this:

```
class IndexRequest extends FormRequest
{
      /**
      * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
      *
      * @return bool
      */
      public function authorize()
      {
          return Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo('show all users');
      }

          /**
      * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
      *
      * @return array
      */
     public function rules()
     {
         return [
         ];
     }
 }
```

then in your method:

```
public function index(IndexRequest $request)
{
   $getUsers = $this -> users -> getAllActive();
   return Response::json($getUsers);
}
```

you don't have to check it manually, Laravel will do it for you using "authorize" function of IndexRequest class.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to make this if statement in each function in each controller

Comment: you must check the link I provided in my answer! I think you have to add "FormRequest", please read the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

This way to check multi permissions to decide sho

```
  @php
                        $patients_menu_item=0;
                        $users_menu_item=0;
                        $roles_menu_item=0;
                            if(Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo('Patient Add')||Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo('Patients List')) {
                              $patients_menu_item=1;
                            }
                            if(Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo('User Add')||Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo('Users List')) {
                              $users_menu_item=1;
                            }
                            if(Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo('Role Add')||Auth::user() -> hasPermissionTo('Roles List')) {
                              $roles_menu_item=1;
                            }
                    @endphp
                    @if($patients_menu_item == 1)
                        <li class="has-sub">
                            <a>
                                <i class="ft-users"></i><span class="menu-title">Patients</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="menu-content">
                                @can('Patient Add')
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{url('patients/register')}}"
                                           class="menu-item">Register Patient</a>
                                    </li>
                                @endcan
                                @can('Patients List')
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{url('patients/index')}}"
                                           class="menu-item">{{ trans('website.Show Patients') }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                @endcan
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way checking permission inside controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request; //don't forget to include on top
public function index(Request $request)
{
   if($request->user()->canDo('permission you need to check'))
      userHasPermission('users show active');
      $getUsers = $this -> users -> getAllActive();
      return Response::json($getUsers);
   }
   return Response::json(['Unaurthrorized']);
}
```